# Add text before second occurrence of <p> in a string

Tags: php

I am selecting a string out of a MYSQL database with paragraphs inside:

```
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
...
```

I want to add a div before the second paragraph.

My thought was:
I need to find the second paragraph and replace it with:

```
<div>MYDIV</div>
<p>
```

But how to replace just the second paragraph? Was trying it with str_replace, but didn't work.

Or is there a more clean way to just add text before the second paragraph?

Any hints for a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are really powerful in situations like this one.

With the following regular expression, we use capture groups to identify sections of the text:
`^(<p>.+<\/p>.*)(<p>.+<\/p>)(.*<p>.+<\/p>.*)` ([For detailed explanation on this regex click here](https://regex101.com/r/ODNMnJ/3))

And using PHP's `preg_replace` we insert the desired text before the second paragraph (represented by the second capturing group, that is, $2):

```php
$text = "<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
...";

$textToInsert = '<div>MYDIV</div>';

$newText = preg_replace('/^(<p>.+<\/p>.*)(<p>.+<\/p>)(.*<p>.+<\/p>.*)/s', '$1' . $textToInsert . '$2$3', $text);
```

PHP fiddle in 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/hiYq9

Answer (score 1):

i can not comment so i will do a fast answer. i think you should [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) `explode("<p>",$variable)` then you can manipulate all of your paragraphs individually. you should also check out [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-splice.php) that will be needed to replace your second paragraph.
i hope i was clear.